# How can I call my webmethod in my ASP.NET app in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, webforms

I am building an ASP.NET app that queries my SQL Server and displays an svg graph using NVD3.js. My web method generates the correct JSON file which works when I load it separately (i.e. sampleJSON3.json). Now, I am trying to pass the json file directly into my app but don't know how to do it. I would greatly appreciate the community's feedback. Thank you!

Here is my web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void getTotalForDateInterval(string startDate, string endDate)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vetDatabase_Wizard"].ConnectionString;
    List<keyValues> master = new List<keyValues>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CountAndGroupByDate", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //Linking SQL parameters with webmethod parameters
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@startDate",
                    Value = startDate
                };

        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@endDate",
                    Value = endDate
                };

        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

        con.Open();

        //Get time in milliseconds
        DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime utime = DateTime.ParseExact("1970-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        long startMilliseconds = (long)((start - utime).TotalMilliseconds);
        long endMilliseconds = (long)((end - utime).TotalMilliseconds);
        const long oneDayInMilliseconds = 86400000;

        //Declare temp dictionary to store the lists
        Dictionary<string, List<long[]>> temp = new Dictionary<string, List<long[]>>();
        string[] buildings = { "SSB", "GEN", "LYM", "LUD", "GCC", "MAC", "MMB" };

        //Create building lists and initialize them with individual days and the default value of 0 
        foreach (string building in buildings) {
            temp.Add(building, new List<long[]>());

            for (long j = startMilliseconds; j <= endMilliseconds; j = j + oneDayInMilliseconds) {
                long[] timeTotal = { j, 0 };
                temp[building].Add(timeTotal);
            }
        }

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            //Remove time from dateTime2 and assign totals for appropriate date
            string s = (rdr["dateOpened"].ToString()).Substring(0, 10);
            DateTime dateOpened = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            long time = (long)((dateOpened - utime).TotalMilliseconds);
            long total = (long)Convert.ToInt32(rdr["total"]);

            string buildingName = rdr["building"].ToString();
            int index = temp[buildingName].FindIndex(r => r[0].Equals(time));
            temp[buildingName][index][1] = total;
        }

        //add all the keyValue objects to master list
        for (int i = 0; i < buildings.Length; i++)
        {
            keyValues kv = new keyValues();
            kv.key = buildings[i];
            kv.values = temp[kv.key];
            master.Add(kv);
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        //Serialize list object into a JSON array and write in into the response stream
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(master));
    }
}
```

Here is part of my webform:

```
<script>
    d3.json('sampleData3.json', function (error, data) {
        nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                          .x(function (d) { return d[0] })
                          .y(function (d) { return d[1] })
                          .clipEdge(true)
                          .useInteractiveGuideline(true);

            chart._options.controlOptions = ['Expanded', 'Stacked'];


            chart.xAxis
                .showMaxMin(true)
                .tickFormat(function (d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });

            chart.yAxis
                .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'));

            d3.select('#chart svg')
              .datum(data)
                .transition().duration(500).call(chart);


            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the attribute below to your web method will convert the result to JSON

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<keyValues> getTotalForDateInterval(string startDate, string endDate)
{
 return master;
}
```

also you can use Ajax to call your method instead of storing it in a file.

```
$.ajax({
url:"url/toController/method"
}).done(
 function(data){
   d3.json(data);
})
.fail() //if you'd like to add an error fix or notification if your call failed
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I added your suggested features, but I must be making an obvious mistake. I made a new post with your modifications: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337383/i-am-trying-to-pass-a-json-file-generated-with-a-webservice-to-an-nvd3-graph     I was wondering if you could please look it. I greatly appreciate your help and time!